# Dockerfile CMD command is not execute

Tags: node.js, docker, build, dockerfile, containers

I wrote this Dockerfile. It should build the app and then run it into the container which I create, but it doesn't work. When I create a container with that image, `CMD` commands is not execute and the site is not running. But it works when I `exec` the container and type it manually.

```
FROM node:16 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:16
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install serve
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
CMD ["npx", "serve"]
```

Comment: How exactly are you starting the resulting container?  What output do you get; why do you think the `CMD` isn't getting run?

Comment: Can you include your `docker run` command?